# Download link HTML

Tags: html

I have two websites, one being a personal side I created, the other a Weebly website.  I'm in the process of porting over the Weebly site to my own.

The Weebly site has several download links.  Upon clicking on the link, the download starts immediately.  But on my personal site, when the download button is clicked, it opens a view page on Dropbox, which the user then has to click through to download.  I'll not include the Weebly site, but here's the (non-functioning) corresponding code on my personal site:

```
<form action="https://www.dropbox.com/s/z5st6y6prq02kef/HCE.jpg?dl=1" 
target="_blank">
    <center><button class="button3">download</button></center>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the solution just after asking.  I was dumb.

```
<a href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/z5st6y6prq02kef/HCE.jpg?dl=1" 
target="_blank">
    <center><button class="button3">download</button></center>
</form>
```

I wanted to go directly to the link "https://www.dropbox.com/s/z5st6y6prq02kef/HCE.jpg?dl=1", so I should have just used:

```
<a href="link">download</a>
```

Comment: Know that the `<center>` tag doesn't exist anymore and shouldn't be used.

Comment: @j08691 Doesn't exist?  I'm not sure if I follow.  It works as intended.

Comment: Hopefully this will clear things up for you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center